# CodeIgniter routing - end slash

Tags: url

Is there a routing rule in codeigniter, to remove the end slash of a url ?

I want my url look like this http://example.com
not like this http://example.com/

For the moment my urls are accessible by the two way.

So is there a routing rule for that ?

Thanks

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: thanks, so to be more specific, so with all the research i made, i have found i can do this witin the htaccess, but ihave not found, if there is a rule that exist to do thaht in codeigniter routing. i have read the codeigniter routing https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html and found nothing about end slash.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with CodeIgniter, nor does it matter at all. `http://example.com` and `http://example.com/` are the same thing - the trailing slash is just "assumed" if it doesn't exist.

And no, you can't control that.